# Bash - increment IPv6 address by 1

Tags: bash, ipv6

I'm currently experimenting with a little bash script.
I have an IPv6 address (via mysql query) in a variable and want to increment it by 1 (by also honoring the IPv6 rules [hex]). Any hint how to achieve this?

Is there a simple way in bash to increment a given address by 1? (this is to avoid duplicates).

Basically:
2001::0000:fe04 is given and I want the script to manipulate the variable to output 2001::0000:fe05, 2001::0000:fe06 and after 2001::0000:fe09 it should be 2001::0000:fe0a - 2001::0000:fe0f followed by 2001::0000:fe10 (hex count). If all ip's are full (2001::0:ffff) it should use the next IP subnet by honoring IPv6 subnetting.
So after 2001::0:ffff the next address would be 2001::0001:0001

Hope you understand what I mean ;)

Comment: This might help: [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: The text representations of IP addresses are just to make it easier for humans to read, and they are not the actual IP addresses used. To perform proper IP math, you must convert the text representation of the IP address to an unsigned integer (32-bit for IPv4 and 128-bit for IPv6), perform the math on the unsigned integer, then convert it back to the text representation. Trying to manipulate the text reorientation can lead to errors.

Comment: converting it sounds great - but I cant find any example on how to do that. most folks simply say "bash just takes whatever format it pleases"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will add 1 to your ip6 address using the `Net::IP` perl package.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use Net::IP qw(ip_inttobin ip_bintoip);

my $ip = Net::IP->new('2001::0000:fe05') || die;

print ("IP  : ".$ip->ip()."\n");
print ("Sho : ".$ip->short()."\n");
print ("Int : ".$ip->intip()."\n");

# add 1 to the address
my $next_bin = ip_inttobin($ip->intip + 1, $ip->version);
my $next = Net::IP->new(ip_bintoip($next_bin, $ip->version));

print "\nAfter incrementing by 1\n";
print ("IP  : ".$next->ip()."\n");
print ("Sho : ".$next->short()."\n");
```

```
$ perl ip6_test.pl 
IP  : 2001:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:fe05
Sho : 2001::fe05
Int : 42540488161975842760550356425300311557

After incrementing by 1
IP  : 2001:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:fe06
Sho : 2001::fe06
```